# Let $ X $ Be the Number of Faces that Never Showed Up in $ n $ Dice Rolls - What's $ \mathbb{E} \left[ X \right] $?

Tags: probability, expectation

This is a example from a book.
Suppose a fair die is rolled n times, and let X be the number of faces that never show up in these n rolls. $E(X)=?$

The method as suggested in the book is:-

Define $A_i=$ $i^{th}$ face is missing .
$\therefore X= \sum_{i=1}^{6}A_i$.

Here is my problem , According to the method suggested above,$ X$ can take values from {0,1,2...6}.

Then the sample space of $ X={0,1,2,3,4,5}$, since at least 1 face has to show up in the n rolls.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Keep in mind, Expected Value is linear even if (as here) the variables are dependent.

Comment: It cannot take value six.  Do not confuse yourself with how the summation of random variables work.  Remember that these variables are *dependent* on one another, not independent.

Comment: Maybe it clarifies things if you let $A_i$ denote the indicator variable for the absence of the $i^{th}$ face.  That is $A_i$=1 if the $i^{th}$ face does not appear, and $A_i=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Something else to point out... by using the suggestion of indicator random variables and noting that $X=\sum\limits_{i=1}^6 A_i$, *we get to completely bypass* all of the struggle of explicitly calculating $Pr(X=1),Pr(X=2),Pr(X=3),\dots$ which would have otherwise been necessary if you were to approach the calculation directly by the definition which would have been quite a bit of a challenge given the tools you currently have available.  The linearity of expectation is a valuable and often very useful tool in probability.

Comment: 6 happens when n = 0.

Comment: @JMoravitz I have a little knowledge of indicator r.v's. But In this case the sample the sample space is changing.This didnot happen in the coupon collector problem.

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong.  Would this simpler example convince you?  Toss a fair coin, and let the indicator variables $A_H=$ head shows, $A_T=$ tail shows.  Let $X= A_H + A_T=$ the no. of heads OR tails that shows.  Clearly, $X \equiv 1$.  But if you just look at the summation $A_H + A_T$, it would SEEM that this summation can have values $\{0, 1, 2\}$.  The fact that it SEEMS that way, does not mean it actually can take all those values (due to dependence).  Same for your $\sum^6_{i=1} A_i$, which SEEMS to take values 0 through 6 but in reality only takes values 0 through 5.

Comment: @antkam Thank you. Your example made a lot of things clear. Would you know how to formulate indicator random variables .Are there any constraints that i should keep in mind ?

Comment: An indicator variable $I_E$ simply means whether event $E$ happens or not. There are no constraints. Then you can write equations on them, also no constraints (as long as the equations are valid in the problem context).  The question is what do you do next.  :)  The most common/basic use is then take expectations and rely on Linearity of Expectations, even when the indicators are dependent, as in your example and mine.  OTOH if you want the distribution $Pr(X=x)$ (for your example), I dont think the indicators $A_i$ would be very helpful.  (The summation is still valid, just not helpful.)

Answer (score 1):

By way  of enrichment here  is how to  solve it using  EGFs. Supposing
that the die has $q$ faces and  is rolled $n$ times we have from first
principles for the expectation

$$\mathrm{E}[X] = \frac{1}{q^n} \sum_{p=0}^q p {q\choose q-p}
n! [z^n] (\exp(z)-1)^{q-p}
\\ = n! [z^n]  (\exp(z)-1)^q
\frac{1}{q^n} \sum_{p=0}^q p {q\choose p}
(\exp(z)-1)^{-p}
\\ = n! [z^n]  (\exp(z)-1)^q
\frac{q}{q^n} \sum_{p=1}^q {q-1\choose p-1}
(\exp(z)-1)^{-p}
\\ = n! [z^n]  (\exp(z)-1)^{q-1}
\frac{q}{q^n} \left(1+\frac{1}{\exp(z)-1}\right)^{q-1}  
\\ = n! [z^n] \frac{q}{q^n} \exp((q-1)z)
= \frac{q}{q^{n}} (q-1)^n = q\left(1-\frac{1}{q}\right)^n.$$

What we  see here  confirms the result  from linearity  of expectation
with $q$ indicator  variables for each possible  value and $(1-1/q)^n$
the probability of that value not appearing.

Observe that this technique will produce higher factorial moments
and hence the variance, e.g. we get

$$\mathrm{E}[X(X-1)] = n! [z^n]  (\exp(z)-1)^q
\frac{q(q-1)}{q^n} \sum_{p=2}^q {q-2\choose p-2}
(\exp(z)-1)^{-p}
\\ = n! [z^n]  (\exp(z)-1)^{q-2}
\frac{q(q-1)}{q^n} \left(1+\frac{1}{\exp(z)-1}\right)^{q-2}
\\ = n! [z^n] \frac{q(q-1)}{q^n} \exp((q-2)z)
= \frac{q(q-1)}{q^{n}} (q-2)^n =
q(q-1)\left(1-\frac{2}{q}\right)^n.$$

Recall that

$$\mathrm{Var}[X] = \mathrm{E}[X(X-1)] + \mathrm{E}[X] - \mathrm{E}[X]^2$$

so that we obtain

$$\mathrm{Var}[X] =
q(q-1)\left(1-\frac{2}{q}\right)^n
+ q\left(1-\frac{1}{q}\right)^n
- q^2\left(1-\frac{1}{q}\right)^{2n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the following property of the [Indicator Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) (Called [Indicator Function - Mean, Variance and Covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function#Mean,_variance_and_covariance)):

$$ \boldsymbol{1}_{A} \left( x \right) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x \in A \\ 
0 & \text{ if } x \notin A 
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \mathbb{E} \left[ \boldsymbol{1}_{A} \left( x \right) \right] = P \left( A \right) $$

Defining $ {A}_{i} $ as the event of the $ i $ -th face doesn't appear.

The, as indicator function of the set:

$$ {\boldsymbol{1}}_{{A}_{i}} = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } \text{The $ i $ -th face doesn't appear} \\ 
0 & \text{ if } \text{The $ i $ -th face does appear}
\end{cases} $$

This gives the following equality:

$$ X = \sum_{i = 1}^{6} {\boldsymbol{1}}_{{A}_{i}} $$

By the Linearity Property of the [Expectation Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value):

$$ X = \sum_{i = 1}^{6} {\boldsymbol{1}}_{{A}_{i}} \Rightarrow \mathbb{E} \left[ X \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{i = 1}^{6} {\boldsymbol{1}}_{{A}_{i}} \right] = \sum_{i = 1}^{6} \mathbb{E} \left[ {\boldsymbol{1}}_{{A}_{i}} \right] $$

Utilizing the property of the Indicator Function:

$$ \mathbb{E} \left[ X \right] = \sum_{i = 1}^{6} \mathbb{E} \left[ {\boldsymbol{1}}_{{A}_{i}} \right] = \sum_{i = 1}^{6} P \left( {A}_{i} \right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{6} {\left( \frac{5}{6} \right)}^{n} = 6 {\left( \frac{5}{6} \right)}^{n} $$

### To Do

- Add simulation.

Comment: I completely understand what you are doing here but my problem is different . My question is that the sample space is changing the mentioned question .Also the number of elements in the sample space is changing. This didnot happen in coupon collectors problem or deriving expectation of a binomial distribution

Comment: Well, it makes sense since this is a different question then the Coupon Collector Problem. By the way for $ n = 0 $ the sample space of $ X $ includes 6.